# fresh Rails-4.1.0rc1 controller index throwing undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

When I create a fresh app with rails and sqlite and start the server and to to the index action for the controller, it does no throw a nil error even when no record has been created. But I do thesame with mongoid and navigate to the index action, I get **undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass**. In the controller index action, I tried using **Message.all.to_a** but the error was still thrown and I tried **Message.all.entries** but the error is still raised.

For I instance, I created a fresh Rails-4.1.0.rc1 app with Mongoid-4 because I am pointing to mongoid  master on github and the app uses **ruby 2.1.0p0 **

I then used the **scaffold** generator to a create a model with just one field as shown below:

```
rails g scaffold message body:text
```

Now when I start the **rails server** and navaigate to **localhost:3000/messages, I get:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `to_sym' for nil:NilClass):
 9:   </thead>
10: 
11:   <tbody>
12:     <% @messages.each do |message| %>
13:       <tr>
14:         <td><%= message.body %></td>
15:         <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
app/views/messages/index.html.erb:12:in     `_app_views_messages_index_html_erb__250078575__604951838'
```

Here is the index.html.erb:

```
  <% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= message.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

here is the model

```
class Message
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :body, type: String
end
```

The controller:

```
 class MessagesController < ApplicationController

   def index
      @messages = Message.all
   end
 end
```

The route

```
resources :messages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bug seems to be a mongoid bug that makes it unable to work well with **rails 4.1.0.rc1**. I know this because followed thesame steps to create two different rails app, keeping the mongoid version constant, that is mongoid points to master. I then used **rails 4.0.4** for an app and **rails 4.1.0.beta2** for another. Both apps worked as expected, that is navigating to the index page does not throw an error even if there is no record in the database.

so the solution is to downgrade to an earlier version of rails.

Comment: +1 I was just about to suggest the same thing. Glad that you figured it out.

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
<% unless @messages.nil? %>
<% @messages.each do |message| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= message.body %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', message %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_message_path(message) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', message, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

It seems like `@messages` is set to nil. It means that `Message.all` is returning nil. You don't have any records in messages table.

**EDIT**

It seems like an issue in the `rails 4.1.0.rc1` version. Try the same code with a stable build of Rails.

Comment: thanks @Kirti. I added that the **unless nil block** as shown in your code but it threw thesame old error. Like I mentioned in my question if you repeat this scaffolding process using *rails and activerecord** instead of **mongoid**, you can go to the index without adding an **unless nil block**, which makes me thinks something else could be at play here.